# IF in superheterodyne receiver

Tags: oscillator

I have a radio which uses CXA1619 IC.

I have a question about the oscillator of this IC.

There is a gang capacitor in the circuit for tuning RF and oscillator and there are two different trimmer capacitors: One is parallel with the oscillator cap and the other one is parallel with RF capacitor.

In AM mode, the IF frequency is 455 kHz and this frequency is fixed.

I have tuned the radio and I am receiving waves from a station. Now, I change the oscillator trimmer cap and then I receive another stations, while I haven't changed RF resonant parts.

How is it possible that while RF resonant parts stay unchanged, changing  oscillator resonant parts (that means changing the oscillator frequency) doesn't change IF frequency and it remains fixed at 455 kHz?

Comment: My text-to-circuit translator is broken so you will need to include a schematic if you want me to say anything useful about this. If you have no schematic look in the datasheet or online if there is a similar schematic and include that.

Comment: Could you please add some punctuation to this question so that we are better able to understand it.

Comment: I have corrected spelling and grammatical errors.

Comment: here is a similar schematic but in my circuit pin 6 is connected to L4 and two diffrent trimmer capacitor are parallel with C1 and C4             http://s9.picofile.com/file/8339938818/Screenshot_2018_10_15_01_23_04_774_com_foxit_mobile_pdf_lite.png

Answer (score 1):

The RF amplifier passes a fairly broad band of frequencies.  The trimmer capacitor allows you to adjust the center of that band to match the desired station.

The oscillator is adjusted to cause the mixer to convert the desired frequency down to the IF frequency.  The IF amplifier stages have a much narrower passband than the RF stage, so they can provide the selectivity to allow the receiver to select a single station from the range that the RF amplifier passes.

Comment: Did you mean when I set the RF resonant parts for example at 1000KHz it passes from 800 to 1200 KHz?and then by adjusting oscillator trimmer, radio receive a frequency between 800 and 1200 ?

Comment: Yes - however the RF amplifier does not have a sharply defined bandwith - if you tune it for maximum gain at 1000KHz, the gain might be down by 3 dB at 800 and 1200, and 6 dB at 600 an 1400 KHz (those numbers are a wild guess, just to give a rough idea of the situation)